# How to filter MongoDB Charts with ObjectID?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-charts

I'm trying to filter a chart in MongoDB by the organization ID of a user. The filter works fine with strings and numbers, but it doesn't work when I try to filter using ObjectIDs.

This gives back no results, likely because "organization" is an ObjectID;

```
const filter = { 'organization': user.organization }
```

This gives me an error (Error loading data for this chart (error code: -1). Unknown Error.);

```
const filter = { 'organization': {'$toObjectId': user.organization} }
```

This string filter works but isn't what I need;

```
const filter = { 'organization_name': 'test' }
```

This string filter works but isn't what I need;

```
const MongoChart = props => {
  const { baseUrl, chartId, height, filter, getToken } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const chartRef = React.createRef();
  const sdk = new ChartsEmbedSDK({
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    autoRefresh: true,
    showAttribution : false,
    maxDataAge: 100,
    getUserToken: async () => {
      const token = await getToken();
      return  token;
    }
  });
  const chart = sdk.createChart({
    chartId: chartId,
    height: height,
    filter: filter
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    chart.render(chartRef.current)
  })
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.chart} ref={chartRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MongoChart;
```

Is there a way to convert a string to a Mongoose ObjectID on the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized the syntax was wrong.

I switched '$toObjectId' to '$oid' and it works.

```
const filter = { 'organization': {'$oid': user.organization} }
```